# How can I make 'bundle init' include gems by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

When I run `bundle init` to start a new project I get a standard Gemfile:

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
```

**How can I customize this?**

My goal is to have a few `gems` that I use with almost every project included by default.

I see on the [bundle init](http://bundler.io/v1.10/bundle_init.html) documentation that it can be used with a `--gemspec=FILE` option, but is there a way to customize the default version that appears when just using `bundle init` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  I've got a template I like to use too, it looks like this:

~/.gemspec_template

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.7"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "pry"
end
```

From there, I just run:

```
bundle init --gemspec=~/.gemspec_template
```

I get a `Gemfile` that looks like:

```
# Generated from /Users/anthonyross/.gemspec_template
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development do
  gem "bundler", "~> 1.7"
  gem "rake", "~> 10.0"
  gem "pry", ">= 0"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> bundle init
> ```
>
> Generates a Gemfile into the current working directory
>
> ```
> $ bundle init [--gemspec=FILE]
> ```
>
> Options:
>
> `--gemspec`: Use the specified .gemspec to create the Gemfile Init
>   generates a default Gemfile in the current working directory. When
>   adding a Gemfile to a gem with a gemspec, the --gemspec option will
>   automatically add each dependency listed in the gemspec file to the
>   newly created **Gemfile**.

All that `bundle init` does is to generate a **Gemfile** from a template, a **gemspec**.

If you want to have a default gem list, just define a **gemspec** template as use it as your **'default'**.

And then just use it like

```
$ bundle init --gemspec=~/.default
```

You can even define an alias for it

```
#note the lack of a space in the alias name
$ alias bundleinit='bundle init --gemspec=~/.default'
```

And then use it like

```
$ bundleinit
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate on what you mean by, "just define a gemspec template to be your default" ?